# How to limit the keep-alive TTL in Go Transport?

Tags: http, go

We have a proxy service built in Go. It needs to communicate with another service however the connection is busy enough ~20 req/sec that Go never terminates the keep-alive connection.

We don't want to completely disable the keep-alive, but rather have the connection gracefully closed after 60 seconds so it forces a reconnect.

Is this possible with the Transport directly or how would it be done with a ticker?

Comment: Calling [CloseIdleConnections](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport.CloseIdleConnections) will give you a best-effort implementation, but no guarantees; if unlucky, a particular connection may always be in use at the time of calling CloseIdleConnections and it may close connections that are younger than 60 seconds. If that's not acceptable you can replace the client regularly with a new one, which creates a new, empty connection pool.

Comment: Creating a new Client *and passing in a new Transport* will create a new, empty connection pool. Just creating a new Client will, by default, use DefaultTransport, and its connection pool.

Comment: @Elliot I am also facing the similar problem. Did you solve the problem